# Why use abstract classes

Tags: php, class, oop

I have been brushing up on the topic of advanced OOP and i find myself asking one question over and over... Why use abstract classes when all of the methods are defined in the child classes. Couldn't the child classes be used independently of the abstract class without causing issues?

Comment: "Why use abstract classes when all of the methods are defined in the child classes" You tell us why you would do that.

Comment: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory

Comment: Because you can override abstract methods in your class if it should do something else and the other 100 method is the same? By the way, this may help you: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/173518/what-are-the-differences-between-abstract-classes-interfaces-and-when-to-use-t

Comment: don't use it. it only complicates stuff and makes code difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

> Why use abstract classes

Some may argue this being a good solution but abstract classes help to follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself&usg=AFQjCNH27hysufwHVMAVfZEp4cSFurM2uQ) while interfaces don't help you with this. This comes at a cost however (e.g. changes in the base class implementation may break classes extending it) and you should generally prefer using interfaces if possible.

> Couldn't the child classes be used independently of the abstract class without causing issues?

Extending a particular predecessor lets you to be able to make different classes extending it be interchangeable.

Let's say you need a bird of whatever kind. The fact both a duck and a hen extend a bird means you will accept both hens and ducks. You may say you only need flying birds and this will mean you won't accept hens (that jcan jump but not fly) any more but will keep accepting eagles. But if you say you need a duck - this will mean you need a duck and won't accept birds of any other kinds. The fact a class extends another class (abstract or not) or an interface will let you pass it as an argument to a function that expects instances of the base class.

Comment: You entire last paragraph is about interfaces instead of abstract classes.

Comment: Actually I don't even understand what you are trying to say with it :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use abstract classes when you need implement something in base class, and child classes should implement some another logic into same method. For example we need to implement services, which parse different type of file:

- we have a base class, which set file name, method for store data into DB and abstract method - which parsing file
- we have implementation for XLS, XLSX and CSV files, which has different implementation for method process.

It's a good solution. But it doesn't mean that you should use that way. You can implement one of the pattern or do not use OOP at all. It is just a one way how to implement a logic.

Comment: I would argue that storing and parsing are two different responsibilities and should not be done in the same class.